# ActionListener not doing anything

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, string-comparison

I am new to Java, so please bear with me.
I've tried to get a button to open up a new frame called AboutFrame, but whenever I press the button nothing happens.

I implement the ActionListener first:

```
class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

Then I set the button (after the usual super("blabla");...)

```
JButton info = new JButton("About Failsafe");
    info.addActionListener(this);
```

And then:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
String command = event.getSource().toString();
    if (command == "info") {
        AboutFrame abt = new AboutFrame();
    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here? I can't see any mistakes..

Comment: add this... abt.setVisible(True)

Comment: Your condition will never be evaluated to true even if you use equals. Did you try to print what `event.getSource().toString();` returns? Just use `if(info == event.getSource())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting the command text correctly:

```
JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
String command = button.getText();

if (command.equals("About Failsafe"))
{
  AboutFrame abt = new AboutFrame();
  abt.setVisible(true);
}
```

Or, if your `JButton info;` declaration is an instance variable (instead of a local one), you could make your if-check:

```
if (event.getSource() == info)
```

Comment: The first solution worked! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (event.getSource()==info) {}
```

instead of `if (command=="info") {}`.

Comment: `if (command.equals("info"))` How will this work? "info" is the variable name, not the command text of the JButton.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. I'm sorry.